# How to only apt-get upgrade Certain Applications?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, apt, synaptic, partial-upgrade

I only have a traffic-limited mobile broadband connection at my disposal. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` wants to get ~500MB of data which is not feasible for me right now.

Hence, is it possible to only upgrade certain applications, e.g. Firefox?

I am quite aware that some libs must be upgraded as well, but 100MB a day won't hurt, 500MB do.

Basically, I want to split up the upgrade-process into little chunks over the month so I don't exceed my daily quota just by downloading updates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just simply write

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

apt will recognize it as a request for update as firefox is already installed. It will also update the dependencies.

Works for every package, which is listed after the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Nice suggestion! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You just re-install the package, For example: if you have installed chromium-browser, when you type "sudo apt-get install chromium-browser" again, system will check if there is a new one in the repository and update it.